# Ηow can I replicate the sound οf this instrument?

Tags: percussion

If you go ahead and [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ki1TC3ShlkI#t=140), the guy with the drums has a percussion instrument with his right hand that produces the shaky sound, kind of like the maracas.

What is it called?

[image]

Is it possible for me to produce the same sound with my maracas? I'm not sure if I'm just not skilled enough with the maracas or I need to buy a separate instrument for that.

Comment: That looks like a [rainstick](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainstick), which is one type of [shaker](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaker_(instrument)).

Comment: @BenMiller I disagree - at least where I'm from, 'rainstick' refers to a much longer instrument, where the beans aren't 'shook' but allowed to fall through the gaps inside the tube - playing in a different way, and creating a totally different sound. [Youtube Example](http://youtu.be/riQNqpwXkvE)

Comment: @Chris I've seen short rainsticks played this way, but you are probably right that it is a simpler shaker that does not have the rainstick pegs inside.

Comment: I've asked [a meta question](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/981/6851) about whether or not this question is on-topic.

Comment: @ben: it is on topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This instrument is specifically a *[ganzá](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganz%C3%A1)* [gahn-ZAH], a kind of shaker of African origins and very common in Brazil. It is fairly inexpensive and can be easily found at music instrument stores around the world.

You can ghetto-replicate its sound by putting some small pebbles or large-grained sand into any Aluminium canister (cocktail shakers make for a very nice visual and sounding effect!).

Answer (score 3):

This is generally just called a 'shaker'.

In terms of creating the same sound with maracas: the sounds are pretty close anyway! Try holding the maracas the wrong way up (with your hand around the bulb), which will dampen the sound a little, and sound closer to the shaker in this video. Doing this will create basically the same thing as an [egg shaker](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=egg%20shakers&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB567GB567&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=E51XVMKhH7WQsQSatQE&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg&biw=1366&bih=643), which are often used interchangably with the cylindrical ones, such as in this video.

Failing that, they're not expensive, you can pick them up for a few quid - or make you're own if you're feeling adventurous!